# How to direct domain to exact apps

Tags: dns, centos, centos7, virtualhost, vhosts

I have made an "A record" to my domain and I have pointed it to my exact apps, it works when I accessed on https://www.example.com but the problem is when I tried to access https://example.com it redirected it to testing apache.

Here is it my config v-host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       ServerAlias www.example.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweb

       <Directory /var/www/html/myweb>
              AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is it my ssl conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName example.com
       ServerAlias www.example.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web

       <Directory /var/www/html/web>
              AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias www.example.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What should I do?

Comment: we need to see https configuration, `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: @DusanBajic i have edited my question adding my ssl conf

Comment: Check if there is any other .conf file with `<VirtualHost *:443>

Comment: @DusanBajic i have but i cant find anything this is file that i found but i got nothing /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf, /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf, /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf